# Apply a formula in OpenOffice on the whole column without scrolling

Tags: excel-formula, openoffice-calc

I have an OpenOffice Calc sheet and need to apply a formula I programmed on the first row to the whole column. Normally I always did that by dragging the formula down to the end of the column data, but it won't work here, as the sheet is very long.

Well, theoretically it could work, but I wouldn't like to sit there for an hour or so waiting for the scrolling to the end...

There should be another clever way to achieve it faster, shouldn't it? ;)

Comment: There are tricks to scroll or extend the selection to the end (without using the mouse). It involves the "End" key. (I can't recall the exact key sequence, but it shouldn't be difficult to find.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also type the range you want to select into the "Name box" that is to the left of the formula box.  For example, if you wanted to paste A1 to the 2000 rows below it, you would:

- Copy A1
- Type into the name box: `A2:A2001`
- Hit Enter
- Paste

Comment: Thank you - this worked! But I have a strange issue: My Calc sheet is rather long and has totally 96871 rows. My formula is as simple as "=GROSS2(E2)" (Sentence case for the string in the column E). Now, if I do what you proposed, OpenOffice will indeed copy the formula down to the very end of the document. The weird thing is, that the last data row where the formula works is the line =GROSS2(E34467), After that row the formula is there, but no data gets processed anymore. Is it a bug in Calc? The behavior is reproducible on my OSX and Windows machines with OpenOffice 4.1.1.

Comment: @QB new media That is strange behavior.  To try getting the cells working, maybe do Tools->Cell Contents->Recalculate?

Answer (score 1):

Try to select the cell to copy from, copy, then select the entire destination column (click on the column header) and paste. It may take a while if the column is very long.

YMMV, tho - I just discovered mine is actually the LibreOffice version...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this didn't work for me. I figured out that It's important to explicitly select only the rows, where the relevant data is in, not the whole column by clicking on its heading, as otherwise OpenOffice freezes forever...

Comment: 96k rows - ouch - that's why it freezes and possibly why it stops processing after a while with the other recipe. In my case it took around 5 seconds, but with an empty sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use keyboard shortcuts:

- Write the formula in the first cell.
- Click Enter.
- Press CTRL+SHIFT+END. This will select the last right cell used on
  the worksheet.
- Press CTRL+D This will fill the value in the remaining cells.